# PHP switching two keys of an array

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
$array['text6'] = array(
    'elem2' => 'text2',
    'elem3' => 'text3',
    'elem4' => 'text4',
    'elem5' => 'text5'
    'elem6' => 'text6'
);
```

And I would like to change, for example **text6** key with other key in that way:

```
$name_key = 'elem4';

// something action here
// and final array:

    $array['text4'] = array(
        'elem2' => 'text2',
        'elem3' => 'text3',
        'elem5' => 'text5'
        'elem6' => 'text6'
    );
```

How I can do it? I have 105 arrays and I need to change every array in the same way, so when array looks that:

```
$array['text6'] = array(
    'elem2' => 'text2',
    'elem3' => 'text3',
    'elem4' => 'text4',
    'elem5' => 'text5'
    'elem6' => 'text6'
);

$array['othertext6'] = array(
    'elem2' => 'othertext2',
    'elem3' => 'othertext3',
    'elem4' => 'othertext4',
    'elem5' => 'othertext5'
    'elem6' => 'othertext6'
);
```

And I would like to change main key with key number three (key -> 'elem4'), it should make in every array (different beetwen arrays is only in value, keys are always the same):

```
$name_key = 'elem4';

// action...

$array['text4'] = array(
    'elem2' => 'text2',
    'elem3' => 'text3',
    'elem5' => 'text5'
    'elem6' => 'text6'
);

$array['othertext4'] = array(
    'elem2' => 'othertext2',
    'elem3' => 'othertext3',
    'elem5' => 'othertext5'
    'elem6' => 'othertext6'
);
```

How I can do it?

Comment: This is wrong way. You need nested list (children of nodes).

Comment: Look now, I edited my question. The main key is always in an array ('elem6' => 'text6'). I would like to remove main key and change for another key from an array and then - remove this key from an array.

Comment: Please mark which answer solved your problem, @NewbieUser

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, you'd like to set the key of an element in an array to a value of an element in a second array which is itself the value of the first key in the top-level array.  Also, you want to remove that element from the second-level array.

Will the key of the top-level array always be changed to the value of the second-level with the same key?

That is, will 'elem4' always be the key for the value that should become the top-level array's key?

If so, you can do this:

First get all your arrays into one big array so you can loop through them.

```
$list = array($array['text4'], $array['text5'], ... (all your other arrays here));
```

Then,

```
$name_key = 'elem4';
foreach ($list as $k => $v) {
   $new_key =  $v[$name_key];
   unset ($v[$name_key]);
   $list[$new_key] = $v;
   unset ($list[$k]);
}
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coding `'elem4'`, use `$name_key`

Comment: Are you sure, it's a good solution? The names of an values in main array is very important for me. I think, in your solution you removed all keys, yes?

Comment: @NewbieUser, In my solution, I am removing the key 'elem4' from each second-level array and setting the key for that array in the top-level array to the value of 'elem4' (or $name_key).  If you want to keep that element ('elem4') in the second-level array, you can remove the line: unset ($v[$name_key]);